# Directions from xml file

Tags: gmlib

I know you can set a direction, modify with drag-n-drop and then save the result as an xml file.
Is there a way to load this xml again to be shown on the map? 
I tried something like:

```
DirectionsResult := TDirectionsResult.Create(GMDirection, 1);
DirectionsResult.XMLData.LoadFromFile('results.xml');
GMDirectionRota.Execute;
```

Any Ideia?

Comment: No, you can't load this xml file. You need to call again execute method with start and end address

Comment: Tanks so much cadetill.

Answer (score 0):

There is limitation to calculate the direction ?

I added more than 10 point stop and not display anything on the map.

Marcio

Comment: Please avoid asking further questions in an answer. If you have a question, ask a question, don't answer a question with another question.